# grails, calling edit in view:A from view B using ajax

Tags: ajax, redirect, grails

When clicking in a field in a table of view (B) in controller B I use ajax to display the edit view (A) of controller (A).

It's just simple as that but I cannot make it work. With the following script, nothing happens.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( document ).on('click', '.prodID', function ( event ){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${g.createLink( controller:'prodBuffer', action:'edit' )}',
                    data: {id:this.id},
                    type: 'post'
                }).success( function ( data ) { 
                        window.location = ${createLink(controller:'prodBuffer',action:'edit_2')};
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the edit action in controller prodBuffer:

```
def edit_2() {
    println("edit_2 - parms: "+params)
    def prodBuffer = ProdBuffer.get(params.id)
    def suppliers = Supplier.list()
    def plannedVolumes = prodBuffer.plannedVolumes
    println(">>> PlannedVolumes: "+plannedVolumes)
    render (view: "edit_2", model:[prodBuffer: prodBuffer, plannedVolumes: plannedVolumes, sawMills:suppliers])
}

def edit(ProdBuffer prodBuffer) {
    println("ProdBuffer - Edit - params: "+ params)
    def suppliers = Supplier.list()
    def plannedVolumes = prodBuffer.plannedVolumes
    println("%%% PlannedVolumes: "+plannedVolumes)
    respond prodBuffer, model:[plannedVolumes: plannedVolumes, sawMills:suppliers]
}
```

Comment: Is 'edit' is your action or gsp?

Comment: Make action using for ajax and gsp for view separate

Comment: edit is the action but also the view. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, make them separate, give different names, if you are making ajax call to action accept data from params and render response.

Comment: Ok, I give the new action the name "edit_2" and I tried to render the view from there but later on the edit action is called and crashes as the instance is null.

Comment: Remove "ProdBuffer prodBuffer" from parenthesis and declare inside action

Comment: Oh no! it's the same. prodBuffer must be instantiated in some way but params no longer contain the id so that's not possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting `window.location` try adding quotes:

```
window.location = "${createLink(controller:'prodBuffer',action:'edit_2')}"
```

Without them my javascript browser plugin was reporting an error relating to regular expression flags.

Comment: That's working. But this question was probably the most stupid one I ever asked. I have converted my project to use datatables (your advice) which was a perfect hit but also created new problems. And they where probably too many for me to handle at once. But for now, I have solved all problems regarding this conversion. The reason that I think this was a stupid question was that all I needed to do was to enter this line in the gsp:<td> <g:link action="edit" controller="prodBuffer" params="[id:pb.id]"> ${pb.id}</g:link></td>. I'm sorry bothering you all with this question.